# Adding n different lists to list results same list repeating

Tags: python, list

When I add lists to my list the result is list of correct length, but all the lists are the same, last list I added

code:

```
cycle_points = []
for i in range(games_per_cycle):
    points = game.game_cycle()
    print(points)
    cycle_points.append(points)
print(cycle_points)
```

When changing `cycle_points = []` to `cycle_points = [[] for n in range(games_per_cycle)]` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly), has no effect.

sample output:

```
[26.0, 26.0, 2.0, 22.0, 12.0]
[7.0, 23.0, 19.0, 1.0, 2.0]
[21.0, 28.0, 2.0, 12.0, 2.0]
[17.0, 26.0, 4.0, 25.0, 4.0]
[1.0, 30.0, 22.0, 15.0, 20.0]
[0.0, 19.0, 23.0, 6.0, 24.0]
[17.0, 15.0, 24.0, 2.0, 35.0]
[27.0, 5.0, 15.0, 17.0, 4.0]
[2.0, 24.0, 6.0, 26.0, 14.0]
[27.0, 11.0, 5.0, 12.0, 26.0]

[[27.0, 11.0, 5.0, 12.0, 26.0], [27.0, 11.0, 5.0, 12.0, 26.0], [27.0, 11.0, 5.0, 12.0, 26.0], [27.0, 11.0, 5.0, 12.0, 26.0], [27.0, 11.0, 5.0, 12.0, 26.0], [27.0, 11.0, 5.0, 12.0, 26.0], [27.0, 11.0, 5.0, 12.0, 26.0], [27.0, 11.0, 5.0, 12.0, 26.0], [27.0, 11.0, 5.0, 12.0, 26.0], [27.0, 11.0, 5.0, 12.0, 26.0]]
```

Full code here https://github.com/aoskarih/5wonders/blob/master/main.py if it helps.

Comment: Your game object is recycling the same list.

Comment: I print the list it produces and it varies.

Comment: It's *still the same list*. It's always `self.points`, no?